# Android: Is there any way to know battery consumed by our app?

Tags: android, battery

I want to know how much batter is my app consuming(in % or mah). On our phone we can see battery consumed by different apps, how to know this within app itself?
Any leads would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Once you know the battery levels you can use a timer and measure the time between two changes (or initial battery level and first change). using BroadcastReceiver

Comment: But that is battery consumed by all the apps not just mine.

Comment: Oh I understand what you are saying Yeah broadcast receive is only for overall battery level. A way I would approach this problem is by closing all the other apps (although there are will always be one running) You can calculate for that

Comment: Maybe this post/page will be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3771330/3287175

Answer (score 0):

In the Android API doesn't support this currently. The only [available documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) is the one describing how to use [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html) broadcasts, which only supply the overall battery level and no per-application details.

I suppose that even if there are undocumented ways to emulate what the System Settings battery manager shows, they would require rooting.

Comment: Thanks! I know but rooting won't help in my case.